# ViewData Int32 must be of type IEnumerable when viewing from stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I don't know if it is because of the stored procedure I did. But I always get this error

> The ViewData item that has the key 'Department' is of type
>   'System.Int32' but must be of type 'IEnumerable'.

Here's my code :

(VIEW)

```
  <div class="col-lg-4">
      <%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Department, Model.Departments, "Please Select", ((ViewBag.Role >= 2 && ViewBag.Role <= 5)  ? (object)new { @class="form-control", @onchange="onChangeDepartment(this.value);" }:(object)new { @class="form-control", @disabled="disabled" }))%>
 </div>
```

(MODEL)

```
public bool LoadDepartmentsFromDB()
        {
            WorkflowEntities entity = new WorkflowEntities();

            List<SelectListItem> departments = new List<SelectListItem>();
            List<SelectListItem> supervisors = new List<SelectListItem>();

            foreach (sp_DepartmentMaster_GetAll_Result sp_depts in entity.sp_DepartmentMaster_GetAll()) { 
                departments.Add(new SelectListItem { 
                    Value = sp_depts.DepartmentId.ToString()
                    , Text = sp_depts.DepartmentName
                    , Selected = sp_depts.DepartmentId == Department
                });

                supervisors.Add(new SelectListItem { 
                    Value = sp_depts.SupervisorId.ToString()
                    , Text = sp_depts.SupervisorName
                    , Selected = sp_depts.DepartmentId == Department
                });

                if (sp_depts.DepartmentId == Department) this.Supervisor = sp_depts.SupervisorId;
            }

            this.Departments = departments;
            this.Supervisors = supervisors;

            return true;
        }
```

Did I missed something ?

Added :

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Departments { get; set; }
```

Stored Procedure Property

```
public partial class sp_DepartmentMaster_GetAll_Result
    {
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
        public int SupervisorId { get; set; }
        public string SupervisorName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: can you show your model definition for the View

Comment: I already added @EhsanSajjad ..

Comment: where is Department Property?

Comment: Done @EhsanSajjad ..

Comment: i am not asking stored procdeure property i am asking for your model which you have set for view and what is the model of your view to which it is binded? post complete model action and view , it is not clear still